# One-sided buffer command line doesn't work?

Tags: ogr2ogr

I'm trying to create a one-sided buffer from a polyline shapefile using ogr2ogr command line and a virtual file. However, it only creates a .dbf file and not the shapefiles.
Here's the code:

```
ogr2ogr -sql "SELECT ST_Buffer(A.geometry,50, 'right') AS geometry, A.* FROM Polyline A" -dialect SQLITE Buffer.shp input.vrt
```

I have to mention that this code works fine when not putting the 'right' or 'left' parameters.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think for spatialite you can use ST_SingleSidedBuffer instead.

It's listed in the spatialite help under GEOS Specific Features, http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-latest.html#p14b

from the docs:

> ST_SingleSidedBuffer( geom Curve , radius Double precision , left_or_right Integer ) : Curve

It's mentions that the linestring has to be non-closed too.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @SaultDon. But where do I have to assign input, output and buffer distance in this code?

Comment: Very much alike that you had with ST_Buffer. What have you tried?